# Compass plugin with Grunt

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, grunt-contrib-compass

This is a question about how to use Compass with Grunt.
Something goes wrong in the data filling step. I noticed on the console that, when I modify only a .scss file, compass fills up the same file several times (four, five or up to ten).
In your opinion, what does it depend on? Here is my gruntfile.js.
Thank you for your kind help.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

var _homeJs = ['contents/js/jquery.Cinema.js', 'contents/js/jquery.SkinOverlay.js'];
var _homeJsExclude = []

_homeJs.forEach(function (entry) {
    _homeJsExclude.push('!' + entry)
});


grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
        dist: {
            src: ['contents/js/*.js', _homeJsExclude],
            dest: 'contents/dist/js/global.js'
        },
        lib: {
            src: 'contents/plugins/**/*.js',
            dest: 'contents/dist/js/libs.js'
        },
        globalhome: {
            files: {
                'contents/dist/js/global.home.js': _homeJs
            }
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        dist: {
            src: ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>'],
            dest: 'contents/dist/js/global.min.js'
        },
        globalhome_min: {
            src: 'contents/dist/js/global.home.js',
            dest: 'contents/dist/js/global.home.min.js'
        },
        lib: {
            src: ['<%= concat.lib.dest %>'],
            dest: 'contents/dist/js/libs.min.js'
        }
    },
    compass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                sassDir: 'contents/sass/',
                cssDir: 'contents/dist/css',
                watch: true,
                outputStyle: 'compressed',
                linecomments: false
            }
        }
    },
    cssmin: {
        target: {
            files: [
                {
                    './contents/dist/css/ie-css/ie8/ie8.min.css': ['./contents/css/ie-css/ie8/ie8.css']
                },
                {
                    './contents/dist/css/main.min.css': ['./contents/dist/css/main.css']
                },
                {
                    './contents/dist/css/responsive.min.css': ['./contents/dist/css/responsive.css']
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    concurrent: {
        target: {
            tasks: ['compass', 'watch'],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        js: {
            files: ['contents/js/*.js', 'contents/plugins/**/*.js'],
            tasks: ['concat', 'uglify:dist', 'uglify:globalhome_min'],
            options: {
                reload: true
            }
        },
        css: {
            files: ['contents/sass/**/*.scss', 'contents/dist/css/'],
            tasks: ['concurrent:target'], 
            options: {
                reload: true
            }
        }
    },
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify', 'cssmin']);
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple problems here... First, you're `watch`ing your sass files in the `compass` task already, there is no need to monitor them with an explicit `watch` task. Additionally, your `concurrent` task is set to run `watch` again once the sass files change.

This is the logic flow you have set up right now:

1. Start `watch`, it waits for sass OR compiled css files to change
2. When a sass file changes, `watch` executes `concurrent`, which in turn executes `compass`, then *another instance of `watch`*.
3. The `compass` task compiles your css, which causes the `watch` task to detect the changes and run the `concurrent` task **again**.
4. This continues and ruins everything.

So, instead of what you have now, just use this (simplified) config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    // ...

    compass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                sassDir: 'contents/sass/',
                cssDir: 'contents/dist/css',

                // *** remove this option
                // watch: true,

                outputStyle: 'compressed',
                linecomments: false
            }
        }
    },
    // ...

    // *** remove this whole task, in the current config you do not need it
    /*
    concurrent: {
        target: {
            tasks: ['compass', 'watch'],
            options: {
                logConcurrentOutput: true
            }
        }
    },
    */
    watch: {
        // ...

        css: {
            // *** only watch the source files, not the output
            files: ['contents/sass/**/*.scss'],
            // *** run the `compass` task directly
            tasks: ['compass'], 
            options: {
                reload: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The you kick the whole thing off with:

```
~/my-project$ grunt watch
```

Or if you want to run compass first, then watch for changes:

```
~/my-project$ grunt compass watch
```

Comment: I noticed a little thing , compile the file css known that grunt is a bit slow , can you tell me why? thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly, but if it is about compass being slow, yes it is. I don't have any solution to that. :)